# find the arithmetic progression

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

find the arithmetic progression whith given
$$a_2a_5=27, S_{10}=121$$
My attemp is:

$$(a_1+d)(a_1+4d)=27$$

$$5(2a_1+9d)=121\rightarrow a_1=\frac{121-45d}{10}$$
Now we have the quadratic equation
$$175d^2-4840d+11941=0$$

but i didnt know that is correct. please help me

Comment: its my work correct

Comment: It looks good. Dk what is the problem. If you use the quadratic formula to solve for d, you get a weird number. Did you perhaps copy the question wrongly?

Comment: I suspect that it is supposed to be $S_{11}=121$ instead of $S_{10}=121$

Comment: Then, $a_1=1$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=5$, $a_4=7$, $a_5=9$,……. which feels intuitively correct to me

Comment: If you are wondering how I figured this out, I guessed that $a_2=3$ and $a_5=9$ from the equation $a_2 a_5=27$ hahahahahaha